# My fluid sim only shows the domain box even after baking

Tags: mantaflow

I am making an animation with fluid in an incubator. For some reason, the sim just disappeared and now it only shows the domain box like this, even after freeing and baking multiple times. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: This is what my animation looks like throughout the whole thing]

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HIx_qWWK-nEs3PzqjvUNZcVqHULwBW0d?usp=sharing

Comment: this can happen if your sim isn't starting at frame 1. So you should keyframe the visibility of the domain as invisible until your sim starts. if this doesn't help, pls provide blend file since you didn't gave us any useful information about your settings.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HIx_qWWK-nEs3PzqjvUNZcVqHULwBW0d?usp=sharing here is the blend file

Comment: @User23412 please make sure that the file is accessible to everyone. As of now, I have sent a request.

Comment: i changed the access. Sorry didn't realize

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
All I did was disable and reenable some settings, the problem reoccurs when you try to move it from where its at it seems. To fix simply move the case away from the object and realign it over the object!
I have the fixed file if you cant solve it this way

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with various resolutions (32, 100, 150) but 175 or yours 200 failed for me too.

When tested back and forth it seems the issue is between Effector objects ("Acrylic", "Body") and Flow object. When one of the effectors is disabled from sim it works.

So ... my recommendation - use lower resolution like 150 ... or to be more save - create a single effector object "dummy" (just for simulation, not for render) as manifold object (to avoid other possible issues like liquid leak) ... you can use your "Cutout" object.

*Since testing at res 200 is too heavy for my comp I baked just the first frame, just to see if liquid mesh is generated ... so there is a chance it is already leaking ... :)*

### Edit:

The issue seems to be modifiers used at effectors (Subdiv, Solidify) ... when they are Applied it works at res 200 too. But it doesn't mean recommendation above is not actual :)

---

*Notes: Your Flow object partially penetrates Effector object, that can be an issue in a future. Also you will probably dealing with contact of liquid with Acrylic object in render (gaps) ... for that you would have to scale a bit baked sim or buy FlipFluid addon that can handle this issue better ... or to use Boolean modifier to cut out part of this contact surface, but it would be a heavy calcution for res 200.)*